# Titanium backup only shows "Overview" tab

Tags: titanium-backup

A few days ago, my phone ran an automatic update of Titanium backup, which used to work fine.

Now when I launch it, I am stuck on its home screen. I've tried restarting my phone, nothing changed :

[image: screenshot]

There is no backup/restore tab, no schedule tab...

What can I do to remedy this ? Will reinstalling TB be useful ? Will doing so delete its data (like the back uped apps) ?

The phone : Asus Zenfone 2 Laser (ze500kl) rooted with SuperSU, using Android 5.0.2

Comment: Have you tried hitting "Menu"?  Have you uninstalled and re-installed the app to see if anything changes?

Comment: What did you do? It says Backup directory unavailable. Have you tried setting it up from Preferences under Menu?

Answer (score 0):

If @Firelord's comment doesn't work, try:

1. Settings -> Apps -> Titanium -> `Force Stop` and `Clear Data` and `Clear Cache`
2. Rename folder `/data/data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup`
3. Rename folder `data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup` on both your internal and external SD cards
4. Uninstall / reinstall Titanium Backup
5. Open Titanium Backup, go through initial welcome screens
6. Settings -> Apps -> Titanium -> `Force Stop` *only*
7. Restore the copy of the old `/data/data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/databases` to restore labels and schedules

These days I backup Titanium Backup with Helium to avoid such problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Ihad the same problem as you. Open SuperSU and go to settings. From there, uncheck "Mount namespace separation" and then reboot.